# Knockout 3.2: can components / custom elements contain child content?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-components

Can I create non-empty Knockout components that use the child markup within them?

An example would be a component for displaying a modal dialog, such as:

```html
<modal-dialog>
  <h1>Are you sure you want to quit?</h1>
  <p>All unsaved changes will be lost</p>
</modal-dialog>
```

Which together with the component template:

```html
<div class="modal">
  <header>
    <button>X</button>
  </header>

  <section>
    <!-- component child content somehow goes here -->
  </section>

  <footer>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Confirm</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Outputs:

```html
<div class="modal">
  <header>
    <button>X</button>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h1>Are you sure you want to quit?</h1>
    <p>All unsaved changes will be lost</p>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Confirm</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Look to knockout 3.3 - it has what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's impossible in 3.2, however it would be possible in next version, see [this commit](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/58dec530bdc27942c80f531700e611edfb9706fd) and this [test](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/348f9eab6cab5e253d1d663c7b9ed1dcb692206d/spec/components/componentBindingBehaviors.js#L174).

For now to you have to pass parameters to component via `params` property
Define your component to expect `content` parameter:

```
ko.components.register('modal-dialog', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.content = ko.observable(params && params.content || '');
    },
    template:
        '<div class="modal">' +
            '<header>' +
                '<button>X</button>' +
            '</header>' +
            '<section data-bind="html: content" />' +
            '<footer>' +
                '<button>Cancel</button>' +
                '<button>Confirm</button>' +
            '</footer>' +
        '</div>'
});
```

Pass content parameter via `params` property

```
<modal-dialog params='content: "<h1>Are you sure you want to quit?</h1> <p>All unsaved changes will be lost</p>"'>
</modal-dialog>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1k4ujoh/2/)

In new version you can use `$componentTemplateNodes`

```
ko.components.register('modal-dialog', {
    template:
        '<div class="modal">' +
            '<header>' +
                '<button>X</button>' +
            '</header>' +
            '<section data-bind="template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes }" />' +
            '<footer>' +
                '<button>Cancel</button>' +
                '<button>Confirm</button>' +
            '</footer>' +
        '</div>'
});
```

Usage in parent component:

```
<modal-dialog><div>This div is displayed in the <section> element of the modal-dialog</div>
</modal-dialog>
```

P.S. You can build last version of knockout manually to use code above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not what I am after. My goal is to use the markup subtree naturally instead of using a params-based hack.

Comment: @janfoeh Edited, please check

Comment: Thanks Max, `$componentTemplateNodes` was exactly what I was looking for.